# C++ STL map - conditional return

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm looking for an elegant replacement to:

```
if (MyMap.count(x)) return MyMap[x];
```

While this code does what I want -- it returns an entry if one exists -- in the case where the element does exist, it searches the map twice. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: What do you want to return if an element isn't found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map::find()` returns an `iterator`.

You can dereference the iterator it's not `end()` with no need to search the `map` again.

For a trivial example:

```
typedef std::map<char, int> test_t;
test_t test;
test.insert(std::make_pair('a', 1));

test_t::iterator found = test.find('a');
if (found != test.end())
{
    std::cout << found->second;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found";
}
```

Perhaps not more elegant in terms of the amount of code, but more effcient than what you currently have.

Answer (score 5):

This is the typical way to do it:

```
MyMapType::const_iterator i = myMap.find(x);
if (i != myMap.end())
   return i->second;
```